# Do expressions enclosed in double parentheses mean return inside a bash function?

Tags: bash

I cannot explain the behavior of the following program. I'd expect it to enter an infinite loop, but instead it just prints "Hello!". The only explanation I can think of is that the semantics of the expression between double parentheses means `return` in a bash function, but I could not find any documentation about this, so I'm probably wrong.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail

foo(){
    I=0
    while : ; do
        echo "Hello!"
        ((I++))
        sleep 1
        echo "You won't reach here"
    done
}

foo
```

Comment: Did you use `set -e` or `set -o errexit` or run it with `bash -e` or something like that?

Comment: Oh, right, that might be an important piece of context! Sorry about that. I'll update my question.

Comment: Can't reproduce (included `set -euo pipefail`)

Comment: I added `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as well.

Comment: It seems that `((X++))` has an exit code 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the non-obvious effects of `errexit` mode (aka `set -e`). For more ranting about the problems with this mode, see [BashFAQ 105: Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

In this particular case, the problem is that `(( ))` evaluates an arithmetic expression, and has an exit status that depends on whether the expression is "true" (i.e. nonzero) or "false" (zero). This makes sense when the expression is actually a true/false expression, like `(( 1 == 2 ))`, but with `((I++))` the expression increments `I` and then returns it's *original value*. Since the expression evaluated to zero, the `(( ))` has a false/failure exit status, which is treated as an error, and causes the script to exit.

[BTW, I could've sworn we have other questions about this exact situation -- it's one of the common ways to run into trouble with `set -e` -- but I can't find one. If anyone does, please mark this as a duplicate.]

Answer (score 2):

The `((...))` arithmetic conditional construct evaluates the expression and sets its return status based on the result of the evaluation:

if the expression evaluates to **zero**, `((...))` exits with a **non-zero** status.

`((I++))` is the **post** increment operator: it evaluates to the variable's *current value* which is zero. Thus the exit status is non-zero.

Since you have `set -e`, that aborts your program.

Ref: [3.2.5.2 Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html)